# How to crop url image with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried using a [image-crooper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) in flutter, but they only for local image. How to crop the image with url image?

Comment: Can't you just download the URL image and crop it from there?

Comment: i dont know how to crop image when i download the url image... do you can share the reference? or example?..

Comment: try `ClipRRect` or something like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to introduce my developing package [crop_your_image](https://pub.dev/packages/crop_your_image). You can convert downloaded image data into `UInt8List` and pass it to `Crop` widget. Then, it would show up cropping UI on the screen.

You can find a sample app which downloads images via URL and let user crop them.

https://github.com/chooyan-eng/crop_your_image_gallery